# Java OpenCv VideoWriter wont open OpenCv 4.4.0

Tags: java, opencv, intellij-idea

```
public void save(String filename){
    Size size = new Size(this.shape[0], this.shape[1]);
    VideoWriter videoWriter = new VideoWriter(filename, 0, this.fps , size, true);
    System.out.println(videoWriter.open(filename, 0, this.fps , size, true));
    for(Mat frame : this.frames) {
        videoWriter.write(frame);
    }
    videoWriter.release();
}
```

Im using java jdk 14.0.2, OpenCv 4.4.0 and Intellij
Im trying to combine the frames in the ArrayList this.frames.
When i check if videoWriter is open it returns false.
Iv'e tried OpenCv 3.4.0 which managed to create a file but not write to it.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the ffmpeg dll found in the bin folder of the opencv zip to the location of the opencv_440.dll.